# Power Bi: Filter the page by a column

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have a dataset of this type::

| Date | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01 | 134 | 643 |
| 2023/02 | 221 | 431 |

I have a pie chart, consisting of the values of the column "Value 1" and "Value 2".

Currently, filtering directly from the pie chart does not automatically update the other charts on the page.

I would like to create a filter that allows me to view the pie chart and the others on the page only for Value 1 or Value 2, thus excluding the unfiltered column.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean cross-highlight? Selecting a pie segment should cross-filter the other visuals?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape your table to:

| Date | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01 | Value 1 | 134 |
| 2023/01 | Value 2 | 643 |
| 2023/02 | Value 1 | 221 |
| 2023/02 | Value 2 | 431 |

This is easily done in PowerQuery. Select columns `Value 1` and `Value 2` and then select `Unpivot Columns` in the Transform tab in the ribbon.

Once you have this, all will work as expected. And this is the recommended shape.

---

The alternative, if you can't or don't want to change your data model shape, is to create a new table and measure.

1. Create a new single column table (let's call it `Dim Category`):

| Category |
| --- |
| Value 1 |
| Value 2 |

2. Create a new measure like this one:

```
Category Value = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Dim Category'[Category]),
  "Value 1", SUM('Pie'[Value 1]),
  "Value 2", SUM('Pie'[Value 2]),
  SUM('Pie'[Value 1]) + SUM('Pie'[Value 2])
)
```

3. Finally, you must use `'Dim Category'[Category]` column in all your visuals, together with the `[Category Value]` measure.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. The method works but it is preferable not to touch the database format. Do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: Updated answer above with option 2.